# How to avoid controls flickering in a CDialog (MFC C++ )

Tags: c++, mfc, controls, gdi+, gdi

Hello i've been looking for a couple of days now how to avoid controls themselves from flickering in a CDialog.

I am using CMemDC and erasing the background to draw some basic shapes with GDI+

```
void CCustomDialog::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC pDC(this);
    CMemDC dc(&pDC);

    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(dc.GetSafeHdc());

    CRect clip;
    dc.GetClipBox(&clip);
    dc.FillSolidRect(clip, GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));

    DefWindowProc(WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)dc->m_hDC, (LPARAM)0);
    Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(150, 125, 255, 100), 5.0);
    graphics.DrawEllipse(&pen, 200, 50+m_interator, 100, 100);
}
```

This class inherits from CDialog and will then itself be a base class to other dialogs to control the "theme".

however when i invalidate and then update the window on a mouse move event

```
void CCustomDialog::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    m_interator++;
    Invalidate();
    UpdateWindow();
    CDialog::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

The Ellipse doesn't flicker at all but all the other buttons, labels and edit controls do.

I haven't found anything to avoid this and i myself do not know enough about MFC to avoid it.

Any ideas?

I was thinking maybe I can set the DC of the controls to be the same CMemDC, but i'm not sure how to do that yet, will post here if I figure it out.

Comment: `DefWindowProc(WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)dc->m_hDC, (LPARAM)0);` - That doesn't look right. What is this supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Try setting `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style of the dialog resource.

Comment: I got it from here, https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/flicker-free-drawing-of-any-control/

removing it doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: @j6t YES!!!!! THANK YOU !!! so simple as well :) feel like a right fool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the style `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in the dialog resource, for example:

```
IDD_STEP_DLG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 344, 215
// here:
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Static",IDC_PREP_HISTOGRAM_PLACE,0,0,343,214,SS_NOTIFY | WS_TABSTOP
END
```